# I am doing this code in php while selecting any database it only display the number of tables not the names of all tables of the selected database

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
    session_start();`enter code here`
    include 'dbconnect.php';

    $q=$_GET['q'];

    echo $field= "Tables_in_".$q;

    $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $q";

    $result= mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

     $new= array();
     $i=0;

    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        echo $row['Tables_in_mysql'];

        $new[$i]=$row;
        $i++;
    }
    echo $num=count($new);
?>

<?php
    for($j=0;$j<$num;$j++){
        echo "here"; 
?>   

<?php echo $new[$j]['mysql']; ?>

<?php } ?>
<?php echo $q;?>

<?php
    session_start();`enter code here`
    include 'dbconnect.php';

    $q=$_GET['q'];

    echo $field= "Tables_in_".$q;

    $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $q";

    $result= mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

     $new= array();
     $i=0;

     while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){

        echo $row['Tables_in_mysql'];

        $new[$i]=$row;
        $i++;

    }
    echo $num=count($new);

?>

<?php for($j=0;$j<$num;$j++){      

    echo "here"; 
?>   


<?php echo $new[$j]['mysql'];   ?>

<?php } ?>
<?php echo $q;?>
```

This is my code please help me in printing all the names of the tables of the selected database in php
I have shown all the names of the database by show database command and it is displaying in a dropdown and while selecting particular database it only displays the number of the tables in it but i want to display names of tables

Comment: Did you forget to post any code??

Answer (score 0):

As you did not post any code this answer is perhaps not what you were after... but this will display all the tables in the current database.

```
select `table_name` as 'table' 
    from `information_schema`.`tables` 
    where `table_type`='base table' and `table_schema`=database();
```